# Is there a third party library available for iPhone/iPad development that could help me make a 2D matrix view on the screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mobile, matrix

This matrix is basically for comparing products in a grid with the ability to touch one of them and to take action based on the touch. The real tricky part is that the matrix should be pannable... with the top row scrolling when panned horizontally while the left-most row stays frozen and with the left-most row scrolling when panned vertically while the top row stays frozen.

I need this in order to compare a large set of products by company and type at the same time, basically a matrix view.

Think of it similarly to a TV guide kind of control.

Is there a third-party library or any other good way to do this on the iPhone/iPad (primarily iPad)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the inner matrix/grid itself scrollable?

It sounds like maybe what you want is a `UICollectionView` for the grid (or just views if the grid is static)  and then two separate scroll views for the left side and top.

*Edit:*

Okay it makes more sense now that you're comparing it to a TV Guide. I think I would use a `UICollectionView` and then scroll views for the left side and top. You can capture scroll events or attach pan gesture recognizers to the `UICollectionView` and then tell the appropriate scroll view to move in tandem with the collection view.

You can use [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView) to support iOS 5. It's API compatible with `UICollectionView`.

Comment: It has to work in iOS 5 and the grid top row and left column have to selectively move and/or stay the same depending on the way which the view is panned.